# Java JAX-RS Web Service Question

Tags: resources, service, path, annotations

1. What is the difference between a class annotated with @Path and a class annotated with @WebService (What is Service endpoint implementation) ?

After reading the documentation, @WebService is used with SOAP where @Path is for REST.

1. Any REST simplest example in java with a web client consumes resource from a service in a same application ? What is the communication method between client and the web service ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Path` is for JAX-RS services (i.e., a REST interface) whereas `@WebService` is for JAX-**W**S services (i.e., a SOAP interface). In principle, it's entirely possible to have both on the same class – there's formally no interaction between the two – though I find it simpler in practice to have next to nothing shared between two service interfaces; REST and SOAP seem to have quite different expectations in detail.

In REST, clients communicate with servers via HTTP. A significant fraction of REST is in many ways just *using* HTTP well.  I wouldn't ever want to try to use REST to communicate between a client and a server in the same process though; all that going through the web-server parts just to go from one object to another? Way to much work when you can do a direct method call…

Comment: What u mean by I wouldn't ever want to try to use REST to communicate between a client and a server in the same process though; all that going through the web-server parts just to go from one object to another?

Comment: @peter: I mean that I have no reason to ever invoke a REST interface from within the same webapp. Too much overhead, not enough functionality gain. Conceptually, it's more reasonable between webapps in the same container, but I'd typically not do that anyway because I'd *actually* be deploying on different servers.

Comment: How do you called the web service as application B from application A (Prefer approach servlet or hard code in UI at application A)?